# AJV - Check property is a function

Tags: ajv

I'm using AJV to check a "settings" object. I want to add a new property `onFeedbackChange` that can be a function (not required).

```
  const ajv = new Ajv({
    allErrors: true,
  });
  ajv.addKeyword('function', {
    valid: true,
    validate: function (data) {
      return typeof data === 'function';
    }
  });
  const validate = ajv.compile(settingsSchema);
```

Schema:

```
  feedback:
    type: object
    properties:
      enabled:
        type: boolean
      saveFeedback: *endpoint
      updateFeedback: *endpoint
      onFeedbackChange: function
    additionalProperties: false
    required:
    - enabled
    - saveFeedback
    - updateFeedback
```

But this fails with:

> Error: schema is invalid: data.properties['modules'].properties['feedback'].properties['onFeedbackChange'] should be object,boolean

I wonder how to perform the validation, and why this isn't built-in.

Comment: TL;DR from [DavidP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61574830/1494454): use `instanceof: 'Function'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're using this to verify data that contains a React component:

The data we're validating:

```js
const config = {
    id: 'dailyGraph',
    component: BarGraph, // <-- react component (function)
    type: 'bar',
    ...
}
```

Our schema:

```js
const barSchema = {
    $schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema',
    $id: 'dailyGraph',
    type: 'object',
    readOnly: true,
    title: 'Schema for validating graph config',
    properties: {
        id: { 
            $id: '#/properties/id',
            type: 'string'
        },
        component: {
            $id: '#/properties/component',
            instanceof: 'Function', // <-- ajv custom keyword
        },
        type: {
            $id: '#/properties/type',
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['bar','pie'],
        }
        ...
    },
    required: ['id', 'assays', 'graphType']
};
```

And the `.addKeyword` syntax as per here: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/147#issuecomment-199371370

```js
const ajv = new Ajv();
const { id } = config;
const CLASSES = { Function: Function, ... };

ajv.addKeyword('instanceof', {
  compile: schema => data => data instanceof CLASSES[schema]
});

ajv.validate(barSchema, config)
  ? res(true)
  : console.error(`Graph config error for ${id}: ${ajv.errorsText()}`);
```

Passing `component` as a string (or anything but a function) throws: `Graph config error for dailyGraph: data.component should pass "instanceof" keyword validation`

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but it looks nice, and very similar to what I wanted to do back then! :)

Comment: Hope it helped. What initially threw me for a loop is the `schema` inside the `.addKeyword` loop should not be named as per your validation schema. Once I figured it out the example in the ticket listed - it all worked.

Comment: This will also work in ajv v8
`const classes = {Function: Function}; ajv.addKeyword({keyword: 'instanceof', schemaType: 'string', validate (schema, data) { return data instanceof classes[schema] }})`